# Play 2x webjars deploy to heroku failed

Tags: heroku, playframework-2.0, webjars

I tried deploying the standard [angular-play-seed](https://github.com/typesafehub/angular-seed-play) project, which uses angularjs and requirejs webjars to heroku.

However, on heroku it throws an error because it cannot find require.js

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Trying to fetch requirejs from the URL
**/lib/requirejs/require.js**

Update:

Thanks for the suggestion James, yes I am able to recreate this locally in `activator clean start`.

I'm pretty sure some configuration in my sbt-rjs is messed up but I don't know what.

This is what my folder structure looks like

```
public
  /ui
    /js
       /myApp
          /controllers.js
          /services.js
          /main.js
    /paritals
        /myApp
            /partial1.html
```

I see this error both during `activator start` and `sbt stage`.

```
[info] Error: Error: /home/sajit/angular-play-seed/target/web/rjs/appdir/./main.js does not exist.
```

The scala.html page which launches the angular app, myApp has this

```
<script data-main="@routes.Assets.versioned("ui/js/myApp/main.js")" src="@routes.Assets.versioned("lib/requirejs/require.js")"></script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem locally with `activator clean start`?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [sbt-rjs](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-rjs) docs it looks like you need to set the `appDir` in your `build.sbt`, like:

```
appDir := "ui/js/myApp"
```

Comment: How would I need to do this  if I wanted to have multiple angular apps? Typically need multiple apps under ui.. @JamesWard

Comment: I'm not sure if sbt-rjs supports that.  Maybe file an issue on that project?